# Html5 android and win pc

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, html5

I use google translate my two questions: Is it possible to learn the ip through html5 video if I have an android and orfox orbot
or through a PC with Windows 7 and tor browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, HTML5 video on Orfox and Tor Browser *should* go over the Tor network and *should not* reveal a users IP address.

I cannot say there are not, or will never be any bugs but efforts have been made to ensure that they do properly utilise Tor and don't leak.